# Stagger the rendering of multiple partials using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I've got the following situation:

#### 1. Using a javascript function to begin an AJAX call

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).find(".loadingDiv").show();
  $(this).find(".matchingsDiv").load("<%= matches_companies_url %>?id=" + currentId, null, function(){
     $('.loadingDiv').hide();               
  });
  return false;
});
```

#### 2. Rendering `matches.js.erb`

```
<% @matchings.each_with_index do |match, index| %>
  <%= (render :partial => 'companies/matching', :locals => {:match => match, :project => @project}) %> 
<% end %>
```

The above code works. Here's a little question: **how can I stagger the rendering of each `matching`?**

i.e. Can I make the first matching render immediately, the next matching after 200ms, the third after 400ms, and so on?

Comment: Do you mean that between each "stagger" the data should be sent to the browser? If so, look into Rails 3.1's HTTP Streaming. Here's Ryan Bates' [railscast on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/266-http-streaming).

Comment: @Zabba - not exactly, I just want the partials to render a split second apart, to create a 'fan' effect as they populate down the page.

Comment: In that case, you need to render everything at once, but *display* each portion after x duration using JavaScript. Look into jQuery animations for that part.